# How to implement a custom type selector in Scikit learn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this `Pipeline`:

```
transformer = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[       
        ('numericals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector(np.number)),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ])),       
        ('categoricals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('category')),
            ('labeler', StringIndexer()),
            ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
        ])) 
    ])),
    ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(LinearSVC())),
    ('classifier', SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo'))
])
```

Where this is implementation of TypeSelector:

```
class TypeSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, dtype):
        self.dtype = dtype

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        return X.select_dtypes(include=[self.dtype])

class StringIndexer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        return X.apply(lambda s: s.cat.codes.replace(
            {-1: len(s.cat.categories)}
        ))
```

Now training and prediction work fine. But I want feature names. I read a lot in github but nothing works. I tried something like this:

```
transformer.named_steps['features'].get_feature_names()
```

But still I get this `AttributeError: Transformer numericals (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.` How can I implement that custom type selector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is complicated, as sklearn doesn't provide get_feature_names for Pipeline. Scalers and your custom transformers don't provide feature names either. There are several tickets open for fixing this (see e.g. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6424, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6425).

There are two possible workarounds:

1) build feature names manually. You need to consider SelectFromModel indices, and feature names from the Pipeline before it.

2) use a library. We created https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5 for such purposes; it supports getting feature names from Pipeline, FeatureUnion and many built-in transformers, and you can extend it to support your transformers or missing sklearn transformers. See [eli5.transform_feature_names](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html#eli5.transform_feature_names) and https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries/sklearn.html#transformation-pipelines.

It won't work out of box: you'd have to at least register transformation functions for your custom transformers - or implement .get_feature_names methods for your transformers. Usage should be something like this (sorry, it is more like a pseudo-code, I haven't really checked it):

```
from eli5 import transform_feature_names

@transform_feature_names.register(StringIndexer)
def indexer_feature_names(transformer, in_names=None):
    assert is_names is not None  # don't handle it for now
    return ["StringIndexer(%s)" % name for name in in_names]
    # or just pass input feature names as-is
    # return in_names   

# .. something similar for TypeSelector, and for OneHotEncoder as well

feature_names = transform_feature_names(transformer, list(df.columns))
```